# iOS build error: Error - Unable to import Certificate

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

iOS build error: Error - Unable to import Certificate

We have try phonegap build for iphone. But error occur.
Error - Unable to import Certificate - You can fix this here

Answer (score -1):

This has happened to me as well. Try removing your key, generating the .p12 and provisioning profile again, and adding them back to your Phonegap build.